# Multiple clients connected to a single server gRPC-java

Tags: grpc-java

I'm trying to build a server that has 6 clients connected with gRPC-java.
My question is, how do I do to have this 6 clients connected to a single server?
Does anyone can send me an example of how I do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally the process is not that different between having one client connect to a server vs. six. The gRPC server is multithreaded and will simultaneously accept connections from multiple clients.

You can quickly try this out with the [hello world example](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/). You can first run the Greeter server in the example and then start six different client processes at the same time. They should all connect to the server and execute the server side code.

In case you are thinking of six long running persistent connections, you might be interested in a streaming RPC. The [basic tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/basics/) can get you started with those.

Comment: And how can I make this clients communicate with each other? How can I make, e.g. Client A communicates with Client B?

Comment: If with communicate you specifically mean making gRPC calls, then your client processes would also have to act as servers that other clients connect to.

Comment: Okay, I will have to look more in to that. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. Instead making my clients act as servers, couldn't make my server redirect the messages to the client? E.g. Client A --> Server ----> Client B